# Difference between a while loop and using after to repeatedly call a function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tkinter, while-loop

What is the difference between

```
def after_func():
    while True:
        now_time.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S'))
        time.sleep(1)

root = Tk()
now_time = Label(text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S'))
now_time.pack()
root.after(10, after_func)
root.mainloop()
```

and

```
def after_func():
    now_time.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S'))
    root.after(1000, after_func)            
root = Tk()
now_time = Label(text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S'))
now_time.pack()
root.after(10, after_func)
root.mainloop()
```

Why does the first one give a not responding message while the second one results in a clock that updates every one second? In my opinion the two codes should yield the same result.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: `root.after` creates a callback to the function you give it and continues running other code. This is not the same as a recursive function because the second `after` is not a child of the first one in the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical difference is that the code using `root.after` allows the event loop (`mainloop`) to process events between each iteration. The `while` loop does not. Tkinter applications depend on the event loop for almost everything, including requests from the OS or the app itself to redraw the window when it detects a change in what should be displayed.

You can *almost* get the same results with a `while` loop by calling `root.update` within the loop, but that not recommended. Plus, the use of `sleep` does exactly what the name implies: the entire program goes to sleep for a second. During that second, your app will become completely unresponsive.

Technically speaking, the version with `after` isn't recursive. All it does is put itself on a queue to be called later. The call stack doesn't get any bigger.

Comment: By using root.after, the recursive function acts as a thread along with the mainloop?

Comment: @Dr.danks: no, it does not act like a thread. It simply puts the function in a queue. Tkinter is single threaded. The function will run as tkinter processes items on the queue.

Comment: Will the recursion of the function occur exactly after 1000 ms, as specified in the after method, or will the input in queue affect it?

Comment: @Dr.danks: the input in the queue will affect it.